# How to push a new element into existing array or create one if it doesn't exist yet in MongoDb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a script creating a document, updating it and cleaning up.

```
db.getCollection('things').insert( { _id: 1001, 
  elemo: { a: "A", b: "B" }, 
  histo: [ ] } } )
db.getCollection('things').update( { _id: 1001 },
  [ { $set: { 
    histo: { $concatArrays: [ "$histo", ["$elemo"] ] } } } ] )
db.getCollection("things").find({ _id: 1001})
db.getCollection('things').remove({ _id: 1001 })
```

For certain reasons, I'd like to retain the functionality but can't guarantee that the originally empty array actually exists. I need to perform my update in such a way so that an existing array will get an additional element, while a non-existing (yet) one will get created (including said element).

```
db.getCollection('things').insert( { _id: 1001, 
  elemo: { a: "A", b: "B" } } )
db.getCollection('things').update( { _id: 1001 },
  [ { $set: { 
    histo: { $concatArrays: [ "$histo", ["$elemo"] ] } } } ] )
db.getCollection("things").find({ _id: 1001})
db.getCollection('things').remove({ _id: 1001 })
```

The above only creates the field but its value is `null`, and so additional amendments to it result in `null`. I'm rather certain that it needs something more around `$concatArrays` but I can't figure out what.  First, I thought I could go [`$ifnull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) but it didn't recognize that command (no error, no insertion, no coalescing, nothing).

Comment: `elemo` is an object whereas `histo` is an array. I am assuming that you are trying to push `elemo` object to `histo` array. But if the key doesn't exist, it will update as null. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @hhharsha36 It is not. I'm embracing `$elemo` with brackets making it an array (consisting of a single item) right prior to the concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `$cond` or `$ifNull` (as you guessed) to check if the key exists or not inside the `$concatArrays` operator.

**Using `$cond` Method**

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1001
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      histo: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$not": [
                  "$histo"
                ]
              },
              "then": [],
              "else": "$histo",
              
            }
          },
          [
            "$elemo"
          ],
          
        ],
        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dYV4faZ9wsP)

**Using `$ifNull` Method**

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1001
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      histo: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$histo",
              []
            ],
            
          },
          [
            "$elemo"
          ],
          
        ],
        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4B8BzNP6bel)

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I though the operator was lowervased so I went `$ifnull` instead of `$ifNull`... So misleading not to get an error there...

Comment: We learn something every single day. Your questions are interesting and very peculiar, as even I learn something new along the way while trying to answer questions. Keep asking for more :)